# Connect to postgresql server on OpenBSD

Tags: postgresql, unix, server, openbsd

Hi I've been hitting my head against the wall for a while on this one and can't figure it out.
I'm trying to set up a postgresql server on my OpenBSD box and can't connect from outside.
Currently I've updated the following:

- Added the following line to pg_hba.conf:

  `host  all     all     0.0.0.0/0     md5`
- Updated postgresql.conf listen addresses `listenaddresses = '*'`
- Successfully restarted postgresql
- Added the following line to pf.conf then restarted pf:

  `pass in on em0 proto tcp to any port 5432`

Then to test I ran `pg_isready -h 10.0.0.236 -p 5432`.  The response says `10.0.0.236:5432 - no response`.  My local address of my server on the network is 10.0.0.236.  If I run `pg_isready -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432` it says accepting connections.

Could someone please help, I'm really confused here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was mistakenly editing `/var/postgresql/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` over `/var/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`. The previous was not the configured path, so all changes did not apply.